# A counting problem related to twin primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

**Update**:

The chat room for this question: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69953/discussion-between-fedja-and-abiessu

The problem statement remains unchanged (below).

---

Consider the following problem:

> Given the following sets with $u \in\Bbb Z^+$:  $$\begin{align}A_u&=\{x^2:x\in [2^{u-1},2^u-1],\exists s,t \in\Bbb Z^+ : x^2=s^3+2s^2+st+t\}\\B_u&=\{x^2:x\in [2^{u-1},2^u-1],\exists s,t \in\Bbb Z^+ : x^2=2s^3+2s^2+2st+t\}\end{align}$$
>
> prove that $\exists N\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $\forall u\gt N, |A_u|\ge|B_u|$.

**Edit**: it has been pointed out that this problem directly correlates with the Twin Primes conjecture.  This does not change the question.

My approach is to rearrange the specifier equations as follows (using $s_A,t_A,s_B,t_B$ to differentiate the sets):

$$x^2=(s_A+1)(s_A^2+t_A)+s_A^2\\
y^2=(2s_B+1)(s_B^2+t_B)+s_B^2$$

From here, it is almost "obvious" that the problem statement should be correct, and I take the path of letting $s_A=2s_B$ for all but $s_A=1$ and comparing counts of values for each such pairing.  Once I have counted all the differences where $s_A=2s_B$, then I go back and count all the overlaps between $s_A=1$ and $s_A\gt 1$.  When all of this is done, I get a value $N=45$ (which I am certain could be improved).

Is there a more effective or efficient approach?  With such an "obvious" problem statement, it seems like there should be an easier way to get the required results...

Addendum:

I glossed over the details above, but the counting of actual results goes like this:  for each value of $s_A=2s_B$ where $s_A+1$ is prime, there are exactly two possible solutions of the congruence $s_A^2\equiv x^2\pmod{s_A+1}$, and there are exactly two possible solutions of $s_B^2\equiv x^2\pmod{2s_B+1}$.  These solutions exist for both congruences.  Therefore the arithmetic sequences in $t_A,t_B$ given by $(s_A+1)t_A+(s_A+2)s_A^2$ and $(2s_B+1)t_B+(2s_B+2)s_B^2$ each produce the same number of values $x^2,y^2$ within a given interval whenever $s_A+1=2s_B+1$, up to a maximum difference of two values produced (per prime value $s_A+1$).  The squarefree non-prime values of $s_A+1$ account for double-counted values, and if we account all the "maximum difference of two" possibilities in favor of $B_u$, we should effectively count the number of values that $s_A\gt 1$ can take on which affect the given interval and multiply it by $2$ as the "worst case" for the value of $|B_u|$.  For the overlap counting between $s_A=1$ and $s_A\gt1$, we account for the "worst case" by taking the fact that $s_A+1=2$ covers all odd squares within any interval for $u\gt 5$, then multiply this result by all the overlap possibilities for each prime greater than $2$ up to the maximum possible value of $s_A+1$ as $\left(1-\frac 23\right)\left(1-\frac 25\right)\dots\left(1-\frac 2p\right)$, at which point we apply the result

$$\left(\prod_{p=3}^n\left(1-\frac 2p\right)\right)^{-1}=\frac 14e^{2\gamma}\Pi_2^{-1}\log^2n+O\left(e^{-c\sqrt{\log n}}\right)$$

(from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/22435/86846).

This question is cross-posted from Math.SE (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2521575/86846) following an intense period of no activity whatsoever.

Comment: In other words, the OP has just found a fancy reformulation of the statement that the number of twin primes between $u-1$ and $2u-1$ is not larger than the number of twin primes between $2u-1$ and $4u-1$, called it "a small consideration", and posted it on MO in the hope that people will figure it out once the big name is detached. That's smart, but the problem is *really* hard even to somebody who cannot recognize it or has never heard of it. Normally I wouldn't spoil the fun, but attaching a bounty to it is a bit too much to my taste :lol:

Comment: @fedja: I didn't attach this bounty, but I did attach one to the cross-post on Math.SE.  This particular problem wasn't difficult once I knew that it needed to be solved, the difficulty was finding out that this was the problem that needed to be solved.

Comment: @fedja: I appreciate that this might seem like a "fancy reformulation" of that statement, but to me it's simply the only way I know how to formalize what it is that I'm talking about.  My question is, how can this be stated better?  Is there a way to count these values more efficiently?  Is there a better argument that forces $|A_u|\ge|B_u|$ without the need to resort to this counting method?

Comment: @fedja: The real point is not that there are more twin primes in one interval or another, but rather that given two different sieves which have a specific relationship (as these two do), one of them must be more "dense" within a given interval than the other.  The consequences of this density cause some other conclusions to be possible.

Comment: @fedja: and while I guess it might seem underhanded to make light of the connection to twin primes, the reason to avoid bringing that part to the forefront is that the sieve functions are simple integer-valued polynomials, and the counting exercise is relatively easy (if convoluted), and it seems like talking about the twin primes part just distracts from the fact that they are two integer-valued polynomials and we are considering the narrow slice of a finite interval.

Comment: I just told you an *exact* reformulation of your question. There is no difference between the problem you posed and the one I stated in the comment (we are counting twin pairs $(p,q)$ such that both $p$ and $q$ belong to the interval). The reduction of one to another is just an exercise in elementary algebra. As I said, I was silent and had no desire to spoil that fun until somebody attached a bounty to it. :-)

Comment: I see.  Does your reformulation present an easy method to resolve this question?  I'm not sure I see the "fun" you allude to...  In the broader scope, the sieve presentation is the only way to approach such counts, as counting the number of twin primes "ahead" of where we currently are forces an assumption that there are any available to be counted...  In particular, I had to prove the statement for all $u\ge N$ for some $N\in\Bbb Z^+$, and it seems like your approach assumes the Twin Primes conjecture...

Comment: "...counting the number of twin primes "ahead" of where we currently are forces an assumption that there are any available to be counted...", describes Brocard's Conjecture: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_conjecture

Comment: *I'm not sure I see the "fun" you allude to...* Come on! If you hadn't written "small consideration", there would be some chance I would believe you now. As it is, just accept that your joke (and it was a really good one) has been seen through. Of course, I do not know how to solve your problem because if I knew that, I would have an estimate $\pi_2(n)>c\log n$ for large $n$. Surely, you know that nobody knows how to get that much yet though the humanity is tantalizingly close to it now. What I admired most was hiding $t$ in the tail, so that people would start thinking of elliptic curves etc.

Comment: @fedja: I guess I just don't understand.  I have already proven the statement in the question, and the outline of the proof is laid out below the statement and the bound I found for $N$ is $N\leq 2^{45}$.  Are you telling me that this is an entirely new thing for someone to prove this statement?  I'm not joking in the slightest, and it's taken me almost 17 years to get to this point...

Comment: @fedja: I suppose I understand that the famous Twin Primes conjecture would lead to a lot of skepticism surrounding any claims made about it.  I am in good faith making this specific claim about comparing two sets that happen to have a deep connection to this famous conjecture.  I guess I am asking for someone to take my efforts seriously, and perhaps to suggest whether this specific approach has been tried before and why it failed, and where my outline fails.  I have a more rigorous version of this proof linked from my blog.

Comment: If you have really proved this statement, you have the proof of the logarithmic lower bound on the number of twin primes up to $n$. (well, you still need at least one pair above $2^{45}$, but they exist). The comment box is too small for explaining why it is so, so I'll post the explanation as an answer. Whether your proof is correct or not, I don't know yet, but if it is, prepare for news reporters crowding at your door :-)

Comment: OK, I have posted the equivalence argument. Will you post the link to your full proof now so that anybody who cares would be able to check it? :-)

Comment: (That is if you *really* want to be taken seriously, of course ;-) )

Comment: @fedja: of course.  I’ll even supply the bottom line details in my question.  Give me about half an hour to get it together...

Comment: Even if you need one week or one month, that's fine. But make sure that you include all details: neither the MO sketch, nor your blog version of it are verifiable (any handwaving or "exercises left to the reader" will spell the end of it as far as I am concerned).

Comment: Of course, if you realize that you don't have a full proof of some lemma, it is totally OK to declare it as long as the Lemma itself is stated clearly. What I'm saying is just that the phrases of the type "This can be done but I'll leave it to you to figure out how" are an absolute "No-no". Good luck!

Comment: @fedja: here's the paper link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5KQFxR7gj3JdEFTTjEycE5JQVE/view  the sections relevant to this discussion are 5.1 and 5.3

Comment: OK, give me a couple of hours now :-)

Comment: My verdict is: incomprehensible as written. You seem to believe that infinite products give exact counts rather than just asymptotics and use the phrase "proceeding the same way with other primes" with way too much liberty instead of defining the matching exactly and clearly. The only thing that was clear was that you *did* know that your question implied the twin prime conjecture. If you decide to rewrite your opus in a way more aligned with the standards of mathematical writing, I promise to give it one more try. As of now, I'd rather have my evening meal :-)

Comment: @fedja: ok, I’m not sure how to work with that.  Say that an infinite product gives an asymptotic value with an absurd error term or other constant multiple.  Does that change the math that we have $C2^{\frac n6}$ vs $n$?

Comment: @fedja: I’ve been working on this without any outside help for well over ten years... I have no concept of proper mathematical writing, etc. or where to start.  The point in my question is not that this statement relates to the twin primes, but that we have a potentially-provable statement that can be considered without regard to any conjectures.  Is this set at least as big as this set when we are constrained to this interval?  It just seems simple to me.

Comment: One can reformulate many famous high-tech open problems as questions looking like undergraduate exercises too, but it doesn't make them any simpler, really. As to $2^{n/6}$, I hope you do not claim that $|A_u|$ exceeds $|B_u|$ more than twice because that is *provably* false. So, I couldn't even figure out what exactly exceeds what $2^{n/6}$ times.

Comment: @fedja: the comparison $C2^{\frac n6}\ge n$ is derived... part A: there is some number of values in the arithmetic sequences $(2s_B+1)t+\dots$ and $(s_A+1)t+\dots$ when $s_A+1=2s_B+1$; rather than counting this value directly, I count the maximum number of differences and count all of them in favor of $B_u$; for a specific sequence, there can be a maximum difference of two values since we are dealing with $x^2$ instead of $x$, and the maximum number of sequences appropriate to this interval are limited by $s_B\le 4^{\frac n3}$, giving us this upper bound on this *relative* count for $B_u$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69953/discussion-between-fedja-and-abiessu).

Comment: @fedja: Part B:  for those values in the arithmetic sequence defined by $s_A+1=2$, there was no matching sequence associated with $B_u$, so we only need to count the values that didn’t overlap with any other sequence in $A_u$.  The starting count is half the number of squares in the interval which is $C2^n$.  The number of overlaps that must be removed from other $A_u$ sequences is given by multiplying by $\left(1-\frac 23\right)\left(1-\frac 25\right)\dots\left(1-\frac 2p\right)$ which is the asymptotic quantity mentioned.  We can manipulate the constants into a single quantity and get...

Comment: Switch to chat. I feel it is not going to be short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit** (5/3/18): A significant improvement to the comparison has been found.  See the chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69953/discussion-between-fedja-and-abiessu for more details.

The sieve function $x^2=s^3+2s^2+st+t$ in $A_u$ can be replaced with another function $x^2=m^4+mn+n$.  This new function produces the same set $A_u$, but also allows many of the error terms to be reduced significantly.

> Theorem: Given an integer $x\ge 4$, both $x-1$ and $x+1$ are prime if and only if $\forall m,n\in\Bbb Z^+,x^2\neq m^4+mn+n$.

**Proof** (Contraposition, only if):  Assume that there is an $x\ge 4$ with either $x-1$ or $x+1$ non-prime.  Note that $m^4-1=(m+1)(m-1)(m^2+1)$.  First, suppose that $x+1$ is non-prime with factors $a,b$ where $ab = x+1$ such that $2\le a\le b$.  Let $m+1=a$, then we have $m^4=(a-1)^4$ and $m^4-1+mn+n = (a-1)^4-1+an$.  Since $a\le b$ we have $a^2\le x+1$ and $a^2-2\le x-1$ giving $a^4-2a^2\le x^2-1$.  Finally, $(a-1)^4-1+a\le a^4-2a^2$ which lets $n$ take on any positive integer as needed such that $m^4+mn+n=x^2$.  The same argument applies when $x-1$ is the composite number.

The "if" portion has no significant changes versus the argument for the previous sieve function.

Note that the set $B_u$ has a similar function replacement, but this is not strictly necessary as the set $A_{u+1,odd,even}$ (described below) contains a copy of the values that would be in $B_u$ but multiplied by $4$.

Partition the set $A_u$ into three subsets as follows:

- $A_{u,odd,odd}$ is the set of odd squares $x^2\in A_u$ such that there exists an odd value $m+1$ where $m^4+mn+n=x^2$ has at least one solution.
- $A_{u,odd,even}$ is the set of even squares $x^2\in A_u$ such that there exists an odd value $m+1$ where $m^4+mn+n=x^2$ has at least one solution.
- $A_{u,even}$ is the set of odd squares $x^2\in A_u$ such that $m+1=2$ provides the only possible solution to $m^4+mn+n=x^2$.

This partition of $A_u$ allows an identity $|A_u|=2^{u-2}+|B_{u-1}|$ which can also be stated as $|A_{u,odd,even}|=|B_{u-1}|$.  It is noteworthy that $|A_{u,odd,odd}|$ should have an asymptotically similar value to $|A_{u,odd,even}|$.  In particular, note that we must have $m^4\le 4^u-1\to m\le 2^{\frac u2}$ and let
$$C_u=\left\{x^2:x\in \left[2^{u-1}-2^{\frac u2-\frac 12},2^u+2^{\frac u2-\frac 12}-1\right],\exists m,n \in\Bbb Z^+ : x^2=m^4+mn+n\right\}$$
be a non-partitioning indexed subset of the squared integers.  Since $m\le 2^{\frac u2}$, we have that every odd $x^2\in C_u$ where $x^2\in A_{u-1,odd,odd}$ or $x^2\in A_{u+1,odd,odd}$ is one that could be counted as a "miss" by one of the sieves $(m+1)n+m^4=x^2$ acting on the interval $x^2\in [4^{u-1},4^u-1]$.  The count of odd values $x\in [2^{u-1}-2^{\frac u2-\frac 12},2^u+2^{\frac u2-\frac 12}-1]$ such that $x\notin [2^{u-1},2^u-1]$ is $2^{\frac u2}$.  Each of these squares may appear as a "count difference" between $|A_{u,odd,odd}|$ and $|A_{u,odd,even}|$, and therefore we have $\left||A_{u,odd,odd}|-|A_{u,odd,even}|\right|\le 2^{\frac u2}$.  Adding in the negative space with $|A_{u,odd,odd}|+|A_{u,even}|=2^{u-2}$, we have

$$\left||A_u|+|A_{u,even}|-2^{u-1}\right|\le 2^{\frac u2}.$$

Conjecture:  Using the principle of inclusion/exclusion, we can bound the value of $|A_{u,even}|$ by taking the number of odd squares which will not be part of any sieve for an odd value $m+1$ by $2^{u-2}\cdot(1-\frac 23)\cdot(1-\frac 25)\cdot(1-\frac 27)\cdots$, which gives the result
$$2^{u-2}\prod_{p=3}^{2^{\frac u2}}\left(1-\frac 2p\right)=\frac {2^{u-2}}{\frac 14e^{2\gamma}\Pi_2^{-1}\log^22^{\frac u2}+O\left(e^{-c\sqrt{\log 2^{\frac u2}}}\right)}\\
\ge \frac {2^{u-2}}{u^2}.$$

Combining the previous results, this allows us to say that $2^{u-1}-|A_u|\ge \frac {2^{u-2}}{u^2}-2^{\frac u2}$.  For $u\ge 17$, this says that there is a positive number of twin prime pairs present in the interval $[4^{u-1},4^u-1]$ where each pair is represented as $x-1,x+1\to x^2$ within this interval.

Many thanks to user fedja (https://mathoverflow.net/users/1131/fedja) for assisting me in working out this argument's details and helping me see the failings of previous approaches.

Comment: Except it still doesn't hold water (see my last message in the chat).

Answer (score 9):

This is just to explain to everyone what is going on here.

The conditions are just $s+1|x^2-s^3-2s^2$ and $(2s+1)|4x^2-8s^3-8s^2$ (plus the positivity of the expressions on the right, i.e., roughly speaking, the inequality $s<x^{2/3}$).

Since $y^3\equiv -1$ and $y^2\equiv 1\mod y+1$, the divisibility conditions are just $s+1|x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$ and $2s+1|4x^2-1=(2x-1)(2x+1)$. Thus the numbers *not* in $A_u$ are those for which there are no divisors between $2$ and $x^{2/3}$ of either $x-1$ or $x+1$, i.e. those for which $x-1$ and $x+1$ is a twin prime pair. Similarly the numbers *not* in $B_u$ are the ones for which $2x-1$ and $2x+1$ is a twin prime pair. Since the complement of a larger set is smaller, we conclude that there are at least as many twin prime pairs $2x-1,2x+1$ as twin prime pairs $x-1,x+1$, when $x$ runs over $[u,2u-1]$, which is equivalent to saying that there are at least as many twin prime pairs in $[2u-1,4u-1]$ as in $[u-1,2u-1]$, so once we have at least one pair above $N$, we have it in every dyadic interval above that point giving the logarithmic growth of $\pi_2(n)$ at least.

Comment: I see that you are "back" so to speak, so ping! once again...  I've been waiting until I thought I had something worth reading.  Mostly just the most recent couple days' worth of comments in the chat... the rest is me thinking out loud trying to get there.

Comment: @abiessu Yes, I'm partially back (one month later than I thought I would and still on and off, but back) :-) OK, I'll take a look at the chat, but a bit later.